# rails + prawn (with grid) how can I update this pdf layout to have a block only on first page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdf-generation, prawn

I have the following prawn document layout

```
define_grid(:columns => 5, :rows => 8, :gutter => 10)

repeat(:all) do
    draw_text "bottom-left - text on all pages", :at => bounds.bottom_left
end

repeat(:all) do
    grid([0,0], [0,2]).bounding_box do
        text "TOP LEFT"
    end

    grid([0,3], [0,4]).bounding_box do
        text "TOP RIGHT"
    end
end

repeat(:all) do
    grid([1,0], [1,4]).bounding_box do
         text "ADDRESSES"
     end
end

grid([2,0], [6,4]).bounding_box do
    text "LINE ITEMS TABLE"
    data = [["This row should be repeated on every new page"]]
    data += [["..."]] * 30
    table(data, :header => true, :position => :center)
    move_down 2
    text "TOTALS"
end    


repeat(:all) do
    grid([7,0], [7,4]).bounding_box do
        text "FOOTER"
    end
end


string = "page <page> #{t(:of)} <total>"
options = { :at => [bounds.right - 150, 0],
          :width => 150,
          :align => :right,
          :start_count_at => 1,
          :color => "000000" }
number_pages string, options
```

this is fine, BUT this is an invoice, so I would like to have the ADDRESSES block only on the first page, and the LINE ITEMS TABLE in the grid([1,0], [6,4]).bounding_box on ll subsequent pages ... is it possible ?  I tried many options wo any success ..

Answer (score 0):

merged the 2 bounding boxes into one and added a conditional repeat on 'address' ( only page 1)

```
grid([1,0], [6,4]).bounding_box do
    repeat(lambda { |pg| pg == 1 }) do
        text "ADDRESSES"
    end
    text "LINE ITEMS TABLE"
    data = [["This row should be repeated on every new page"]]
    data += [["..."]] * 30
    table(data, :header => true, :position => :center)
    move_down 2
    text "TOTALS"
end
```